# C#, how to update particular Cell in an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, windows

I have created a windows application in C# and I am using excel as a temporary database.  I am able to read in the excel data, but I have no idea how to update the cell value in that file using C#.

The structure is as follows:

[image]

I want to update the done field to `yes` after finishing the execution.

Comment: You're going to need to look at the OpenXML libraries.  Why are you using Excel as a temp database?  There might be better options.  Do you have to use Excel for some reason?

Comment: @Trent Why go with OpenXML? He isn't looking to use the excel file in that way; he wants to use it for a data source not make alterations to the document markup.

Comment: @emd - oh... good point.  I've had OpenXML on the brain lately.  I'll get another cup of coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to update

```
Extended Properties=HDR=NO; IMEX=1
```

with

```
Extended Properties=HDR=YES;
```

so it will be:

```
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Excel 8.0; Extended Properties=HDR=YES;Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/swtlist.xls";

OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

oledbConn.Open();
DataTable dt = oledbConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET done='yes' where id=1", oledbConn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using excel as an OLEDB data source then you will use SQL just like if it were a database.
Queries look a little like:

`SELECT [Column Name One], [Column Name Two] FROM [Sheet One$]`

In your case

```
UPDATE [Sheet One$]
SET [column1]=value, [done]='yes'
WHERE [some_column]=some_value
```

IF you need more help look around, there is tons of information on this available.
Maybe http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB will help you get started.

Comment: @VishalSuthar I updated it for you. My intention was just to show that standard SQL will work for querying an excel file if it is used as an OLEDB source.

Answer (score 0):

To update the excel using C#, you simply have to get the worksheet object and by using that update cell using the address of the cell (xlWorksheet .Cells[1,1]). See the below sample code.

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
    
    public class Program {
        public string[,] someImportantData;
        public string[,] ExtractData(string path) {
            try {   
                // Excel Instance declartion
                Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
                Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1]; // Insert your sheet index here
                Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;  
               
                // Some code goes here


                // Update the excel worksheet
                xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = 4;
                xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Value";                    
                xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
                xlApp.Quit();

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

                return someImportantData;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex) {
                throw Ex;
            }
        }
     }
}
```